# Can we use discrete cosine transform with imaginary part

Tags: ofdm, ifft, dct

I have been reading about the difference between the use of iFFT and iDCT with OFDM.

What I understood that iDCT can only be used with one phase modulated symbol which is PAM/BPSK modulation.

It means for example 0 and 1 can be mapped into -1 and 1, respectively before using the iDCT.

Can  we map the 0 and 1 into -j and j? I mean in the imaginary direction. Then,  use the iDCT in the place of iFFT at the same usual way? Does that give sense? Is is the same of normal case when mapping the modulated symbols into the real parts ?

Comment: "IDCT can only be used with one phase modulated symbol": Can you tell us where you've read that? I'm pretty certain that's wrong, so without the original source, I don't think we can help you overly much.

Comment: especially, OFDM with the DCT makes little sense, since you're wasting half of your spectral efficiency; sounds like a bad idea aside from very specific systems (which then wouldn't be called OFDM,  usually). Hence, "does that make sense?" is not a very well-defined question. We'll need context: what have you been reading, WHY are you interested in doing OFDM with the DCT. Have you read the DCT [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform#DCT-II)? It explains the relation of DCT and DFT, and I think that pretty much answers all your question.

Comment: Do you mean we can use iDCT/DCT with QAM/QPSK  modulation straightforward ? I mean the symbol QAM or QPSK can be modulated by a  sub-carrier  based on iDCT??   Is that right and can be done ? @MarcusMüller

Comment: I'll not be answering any questions without you giving the context I've asked clearly here; ALL, not just a subset of these questions: 1. Where did you read that you can't? 2. Have you read the DCT wikipedia page I've linked to above, 3. and why does that not answer your question? 4. Why would you do OFDM with the DCT?

Comment: @MarcusMüller it's better to discuss with members in polite/nice way. They are here to learn and get new knowledge. It's better enjoy discussing with them and teach them. Unless, it's not your concern to know everything about the question.  Sorry for that, but I noticed that almost all you comments are similar. . sorry again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have an OFDM system with $N$ subcarriers, the modulated data based on Fourier exponential function can be expressed as follows:

$S_{ofdm} = \frac{1}{\sqrt T} e^{j2nπFt}$ where $T$ is the OFDM symbol period, $F = 1/T$ denotes the minimum spacing required to guarantee the orthogonality between subcarriers.

Regarding the OFDM-based DCT, the modulated symbol can be done as below:

$S_{DCT-OFDM} = \sqrt {2/T} \cos(2πnft)$

you can compare the two equations. On one hand,  the orthogonality in DCT can be satisfied for a minimum intercarrier distance of $f = 1/(2T)$. On the second hand, the number of subcarriers resulted of DCT are double of those resulted from DFT. So, does that mean we gain or loose half spectrum efficiency?  No, that's not right, because, in DCT, you are just using the real part (or imaginary part) compared with DFT which is using complex basis function. That's all simply how we use DCT with OFDM.

Coming back to your question, is it possible to use the real part and imaginary part?  Yes,  you can use one of them and generally, OFDM based on DCT/DFT should give (almost) similar performance.

Comment: you're wrong: by using only half of the carriers (the even ones), the DCT has exactly half the spectral efficiency.

Comment: Have you down-voted the question? I think it's not a good way to deal with members by that way. OK, let's $W$ be the available channel bandwidth, $T$ and $T^"$ the symbol duration in DFT and DCT systems, respectively. Hence, $N$ subcarriers can be occupied in DFT and $2N$ in DCT system since the required space of DFT is double of DCT. So to get same performance, you can transmit only half modulated data in every subcarrier using DCT. i.e  QAM/QPSK with DFT,  and , PAM/BPSK with DCT should give same BER performance (again, DCT should outperform the DFT by 1-1.5 dB). I hope it's clear now.

Comment: You forget that in a DFT-based system, you get positive and negative frequency subcarriers that can carry independent information, whereas in a DCT system, your spectrum is necessarily symmetric

Comment: You are right,Which means that DCT-OFDM is real signal. That's all. So, we can carry BPSK/PAM signal.  for more details, you can check "M-ary amplitude shift keying OFDM system", IEEE trans. commun, vol. 51, no. 10, pp 1638-1642, 2003.

Comment: No, that's wrong, too: You can of course multiply a DCT subcarrier with a complex value. The IDCT will just map that to a real-valued signal. So, we can carry arbitrary complex constellations (since the DCT is still linear). It's really just a waste of spectrum.

Comment: Or are you referring to Xiong's half-spacing methods for OFDM? Then you get the same spectral efficiency as in DFT-based OFDM, indeed, but at the expense of being restricted to a constellation that is only half as efficient as the QAM you could have done in proper OFDM.

Comment: And that's also pretty much the conclusion of Xiong's [paper](https://engagedscholarship.csuohio.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://scholar.google.de/&httpsredir=1&article=1059&context=enece_facpub): At best, M-ASK half-spacing OFDM is as good as QAM OFDM in AWGN. Interesting are the freq-correctability properties! The real-ness of the subcarrier symbols would allow for easier phase tracking, and more robust phase correction, but at the cost of increased ICI in the presence of frequency offset.

Comment: @New_student, I think this discussion is clear enough. you can start your work based on it. To summarize: DCT is a Fourier-related transform similar to the discrete Fourier transform (DFT), but using only real numbers. The DCTs are generally related to Fourier Series coefficients of a periodically and symmetrically extended sequence whereas DFTs are related to Fourier Series coefficients of a periodically extended sequence. DCTs are equivalent to DFTs of roughly twice the length, operating on real data with even symmetry.  Good luck

Comment: That was an excellent conclusion, @Zeyad_Zeyad. Thank you!

Comment: @MarcusMüller .. You're always welcome

Comment: Thank you to both you